# Python stop letter inputs in eval calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

So, i am making an eval calculator for school, and i cant get it to work that you cant input letters. i tried using lists, if/else,"contains", yet nothing works. This is the code with contains, even if the code contains letters, it still executes the "else" line:

```
if calc.__contains__('a'"b""c""d""e""f""g""h""i""j""k""l""m""n""o""p""q""r""s""t""u""v""w""x""y""z""A""B""C""D""E""F""G""H""I""J""K""L""M""N""O""P""Q""R""S""T""U""V""W""X""Y""Z""!""#""$""%""&""\"""'""("")"",""."":"";""<""="">""?""@""[""]""^""_""`""{""|""}""~"")"":"):
    print('Test - contains letters')
else:
    print("Answer: " + str(eval(calc)))
```

Comment: You are testing if `calc` contains the substring `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!#$%&"'(),.:;<=>?@[]^_'{|}~):` - the *whole* thing, in that exact order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. The following checks whether there are letters of the alphabet in calc.

````
import re
calc = "123abc"
list_of_letters_in_calc = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', calc)
print (list_of_letters_in_calc)
if list_of_letters_in_calc:
    print('calc contains letters')
else:
    print("calc contains no letters")```
````

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead. this shortens your condition and is very explicit about what you're after:

```
if all(c.isnumeric() for c in your_str):
    # do stuff if it's all numbers
```